# NA appears where title should be for R package manual pdf

Tags: r, package, roxygen2

I have an `NA` that I cannot figure out how to fix in one of the entries in the manual for my package. It is the first topic, the package itself. It should display the title of my package: "MA Birk's Functions" but instead just `NA`.

Here is the relevant `.R` code for the package description (note I'm using roxygen2):

```
#' MA Birk’s Functions
#'
#' This is a compilation of functions that I found useful to make. It currently includes a unit of measurement conversion function, a Q10 calculator for temperature dependence of chemical and biological rates, and some miscellaneous wrapper functions to make R code shorter and faster to write.
#'
#' @author Matthew A. Birk, \email{matthewabirk@@gmail.com}
#' @docType package
#' @name birk
#' @encoding UTF-8

NULL
```

And the resulting `.Rd` file:

```
% Generated by roxygen2 (4.1.0): do not edit by hand
% Please edit documentation in R/birk.R
\docType{package}
\encoding{UTF-8}
\name{birk}
\alias{birk}
\alias{birk-package}
\title{MA Birk’s Functions}
\description{
This is a compilation of functions that I found useful to make. It currently includes a unit of measurement conversion function, a Q10 calculator for temperature dependence of chemical and biological rates, and some miscellaneous wrapper functions to make R code shorter and faster to write.
}
\author{
Matthew A. Birk, \email{matthewabirk@gmail.com}
}
```

I notice no `NA` appearing in any of the resulting HTML pages nor any errors in building or checking the package. But here in the manual is this `NA`:

[image: NA]

I have 3 earlier versions of this package that never had this problem. For this latest version I switched from manually entering `.Rd` info to using `roxygen2`. I'm thinking the `NA` issue is arising from that somewhere...

I don't think the `DESCRIPTION` file has anything to do with it, so I did not include it in this question (too cluttered), but let me know if you suspect it and I can add that as well.

Comment: It's a shot in the dark, but I strongly suspect the `’` in `Birk’s` is giving you problems. Maybe see what you get if you replace it with a simple  upright single quote, as in `Birk's`.